# What is Ruby (1.8.7) analog to SortedDictionary in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, ruby, sorteddictionary

I need to hold values in sorted hash in ruby (1.8.7). What data structed will fit the best?

Comment: No, i mean sorted in terms of some sort order, defined for hash keys.

Comment: That's wrong. 1.9 hashes are ordered, not sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the core library or the standard library now, that will fit your bill.

There *is*, however, [a feature request to add a Red/Black-Tree implementation](http://redMine.Ruby-Lang.Org/issues/show/2348/) to Ruby 1.9.3/2.0.

If you are able to force your users to only ever use [XRuby](http://XRuby.Com/) or [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/), you could just use one of the implementations of Java's [`java.util.SortedMap<K, V>`](http://Download.Oracle.Com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) such as [`java.util.TreeMap<K, V>`](http://Download.Oracle.Com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

If you are able to force your users to only ever use [Ruby.NET](http://RubyDotNETCompiler.GoogleCode.Com/) or [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/), you could just use .NET's [`System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://MSDN.Microsoft.Com/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

If you are able to force your users to only ever use MRI or YARV, you could use the [`Ruby/RBTree`](http://WWW.GeoCities.Co.Jp/SiliconValley-PaloAlto/3388/rbtree/README) library. It might also work on [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) or [the not-yet-released JRuby 1.6](https://GitHub.Com/JRuby/JRuby/tree/cext/). Note that there seem to be multiple independent updated forks of that library in the wild. It is not obvious, which one of those is the most recent and/or best maintained one.

The *only* solution I know of which is guaranteed to be portable, is [Kanwei Li's Algorithms and Containers GSoC 2008 project](http://Algorithms.RubyForge.Org/), which actually contains two implementations of a sorted, key-indexed collection: [`Containers::RBTreeMap` based on a Red/Black-Tree](https://GitHub.Com/Kanwei/Algorithms/blob/master/lib/containers/rb_tree_map.rb) and [`Containers::SplayTreeMap` based on a Splay Tree](https://GitHub.Com/Kanwei/Algorithms/blob/master/lib/containers/splay_tree_map.rb).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to roll this yourself, if no one else has a better suggestion.

```
class SortedHash
  def initialize
    @data = []
  end

  def [](k)
    @data.find {|kp,vp| kp == k}.last
  end

  def []=(k, v)
    @data.reject! {|kp,vp| kp == k}
    @data << [k, v]
    @data = @data.sort_by {|kp,vp| kp}
  end

  def each(&b)
    @data.each(&b)
  end
end

sh = SortedHash.new
sh[32] = "no"
sh[1] = "later"
sh[99] = "after"

sh.each do |k,v|
  p [k,v]
end
```

Output:

```
[1, "later"]
[32, "no"]
[99, "after"]
```

Array is sorted by keys, so they can be of any call and you just need to define comparison operators on them.

Comment: Yes, i know this solution, but i don't want to sort array every time when inserting values... It's not efficient. I just asked if there is existing solution (maybe it's using some balanced binary trees, or smth like that)

Comment: Not in the standard library, at least. Sorry :/

Answer (score -2):

Use the same class in c# SortedDictionary :

SortedDictionary keyValues = new SortedDictionary();

```
        keyValues.Add(5,"sample5");
        keyValues.Add(2, "sample2");
        keyValues.Add(6, "sample6");
        keyValues.Add(8, "sample8");
        keyValues.Add(9, "sample9");
        keyValues.Add(1, "sample1");
```

Comment: I need a sorted dictionary in ruby, not in C#. Please, read the question more carefully.